# How do you change tcp_congestion_control on OpenVZ?

Tags: networking, configuration, tcp, sysctl

I have a network of OpenVZ machines that I am testing various congestion control methods on. I need to know how to change the congestion control. Currently I get nothing but permission denied. Is it even possible to change this on this sort of configuration?

```
[tylersc@center ~]$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=reno
error: permission denied on key 'net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control'
[tylersc@center ~]$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic
```

Correction: [OpenVZ](http://openvz.org/Main_Page) not OpenVM

Comment: Can you tell us what "OpenVM" is supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say OpenVZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenVZ is container-based, and as such, uses a shared kernel. Containers can only change a very small, restricted set of sysctls (which ones, unfortunately, aren't even documented). If you need to do this, you need to be using something other than OpenVZ.